# Google PubSub ordered Messages to Dead Letter Queue process

Tags: google-cloud-platform, messaging, google-cloud-pubsub, dead-letter

I have a scenario of Pub/Sub with ordered messages and a Dead Letter queue.
Do all the ordered messages land on a Dead Letter queue or just the one of the Ordered messages, that is not able to be processed, lands individually on the DL Queue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right now, it should not be possible to set up a dead letter queue on a subscription that has message ordering enabled. The reason is that dead letter queues are best effort and so it's possible that the redelivery of a message would not be consistent if it was going to be moved to the dead letter topic, which could violate the ordering guarantees.

Comment: Correct. I tried to create the subscription with Dead Letter and failed. Although it is not visible on the UI