# Google Pub/Sub "A subscription cannot have both message ordering enabled and a dead letter policy configured."

Tags: google-cloud-pubsub

Trying to create a subscription with ordering enabled and a dead letter policy and getting the error:

A subscription cannot have both message ordering enabled and a dead letter policy configured.

Why are they mutually exclusive?

Moreover if dead lettering is disabled for a subscription the messages don't include the delivery_attempt field so I can't even do dead lettering myself when handling a message. That's quite unusable.

Answer (score 1):

Duplicate of:

[Google PubSub ordered Messages to Dead Letter Queue process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64700989/google-pubsub-ordered-messages-to-dead-letter-queue-process)

As per your concern about not being able to access your delivery_attempt counter because of the conflict with message ordering, please see the following post for some workaround:

[Google Cloud Pub/Sub Retry Count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38599232/google-cloud-pub-sub-retry-count)